# Shell command to save list of movies to csv

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing, files

I am trying to write a one line shell command (bash) to save a list of movies to a CSV file. I am okay with using a script if needed.

My folders are laid out as follows:

```
    -Movies/
    --A/
    ----After Earth (2013).mkv
    --B/
    ----Batman (1989).mkv
```

Using this command:

```
     ls Movies/* | grep '.mkv' | cut -d. -f1
```

This provides me with a list of movies that I know to be of the type MKV.

```
    12 Monkeys (1995)
    2001 - A Space Odyssey (1968)
    A Million Ways To Die In The West (2014)
    A Series of Unfortionate Events (2004)
    Bad Company (2002)
```

I would eventually however like to end up with a CSV file that looks as follows:

```
    MOVIE_NAME, MOVIE_YEAR, FILE_TYPE, CREATED_DATE (YYYY-MM-DD)
```

Perhaps something involving sed or awk may be necessary?

Comment: Is the year of the movie always in quotes?

Comment: With `ffprobe` (part of `avconv`) you can extract a lot of data from the metadata / tags of the media file. For example `ffprobe -v error -show_entries format_tags=title,date:format=duration file.mp4`.

Comment: @cutrightjm, yes the year of the movie is always in quotes. Always in the format [Movie Title (YYYY).mkv].

Answer (score 1):

This script assumes all files are in the format in the question.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Important! This assumes all files are in the following format:
#
# Movies/A/After Earth (2013).mkv
# Movies/B/Batman (1989).mkv
# Movies/C/Carry On Sergeant (1958).mkv"

raw=`find ./Movies -type f -name \*.mkv`
# Field split on line return
IFS="
"
for m in $raw
do
    fDate=`stat -f %Sm -t %Y-%m-%d "$m"`
    fName=${m##*/}
    fExt=${m##*\.}
    # Assume every movie is in "Name of Film (YYYY).mkv" format
    movie=${fName%% (*}
    mYear=${fName%%)*}
    mYear=${mYear##*(}
    echo "\"${movie}\", \"${mYear}\", \"${fExt}\", \"${fDate}\""
done

exit
```

And the result should be like:

```
"After Earth", "2013", "mkv", "2017-05-14"
"Batman", "1989", "mkv", "2017-05-14"
"Carry On Sergeant", "1958", "mkv", "2017-05-14"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by *created date*, you mean the last modification time of the file (as reported by `ls -l`), then with GNU `find`, you could do (here using [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) CSV format):

```
find . -regextype posix-extended \
       -regex '.*\([0-9]{4}\)\.[[:alnum:]]+' \
       -type f \
       -printf '%TF/%f\0' |
  perl -l -0pe '
    s/"/""/g;
    s{(.*)/(.*?)\s*\((\d{4})\)\.([^.]*)$}{"$2",$3,$4,$1\r}s'
```